# cPanel & DirectoryIndex - server default page showing for domain root

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, directoryindex

I'm pretty sure that I have a very trivial problem and that lots of you guys have answered this kind of question a thousand times. But I just can't find any of these answers. So here we go.

I am managing a hosting account via cPanel. But for some reason trying to access the website's index file by just typing in the domain name (e.g. www.mydomain.com) always shows the cPanel default page (i.e. www.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi). The site works fine if I specifiy the index file name (i.e.  www.mydomain.com/index.php).

At first I thought it had somewhing to do with the DirectoryIndex configuration. So I checked the Apache conf, and everything seems to be in order (`DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml`). Just do be sure I added a .htaccess to the server root with the same directives.

But to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's not cached at your client? Have you checked with a different browser or a cleared cache? I've found that at least firefox is pretty stubborn in caching the cpanel default redirect.

Comment: D'oh! That was exactly it!!!  I just trusted the the old Ctrl-F5 would do it in FF, but no. Just tried it in Chrome and all's good. FF's annoyance factor's rising...:(